# Replacing section of python string with a designated variable

Tags: python, string, formatting

Currently I'm working on a message that I'd like to include multiple changing variables. Now I'm not exactly sure whether I explained that right, therefore here's an example:

> """
>
> Hello world!
>
> %s
>
> %(what goes here?)
>
> """.format()

Basically I'd like to apply another "%s", though I don't know how to do so.

Sorry if this is fairly easy; I haven't been able to find much information if at all on ways relating to the problem described above.

I appreciate the help, and thanks!

---

Edit:

> REPLY_MENTION_TEMPLATE = """
>
> Example message:
>
> %s
>
> {pm_link}.
>
> {info_post}.
>
> |{source_link}|
>
> """.format(pm_link = pm_link, info_post = info_post, source_link = source_link)
>
> exampleMess = (REPLY_MENTION_TEMPLATE % eampleVar)

(So basically, I'd like to add another "%" so I may input another variable)

Comment: What output are you expecting? Please provide an example.

Comment: Sorry, here you are:

(Noticed I can't post it here, so I'll edit it into the post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple key/value pairs to Python's [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format)

> `format(format_string, *args, **kwargs)` format() is the primary API
>   method. It takes a format string and an arbitrary set of positional
>   and keyword arguments. format() is just a wrapper that calls
>   vformat().

**Example:**

```
>>> print "Hello {foo:s} and {bar:s}".format(foo="World", bar="Foobar!")
Hello World and Foobar!
```

However it's probably recommended that you use [String Templates](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings) here or an alternative templating engine such as [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)

**Basic Jinja2 Example:**

```
from jinja2 import Environment

HTML = """
<html>
<head>
<title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>

Hello.

</body>
</html>
"""

def print_html_doc():
    print Environment().from_string(HTML).render(title='Hellow Gist from GutHub')
```

You can *easily* install Jinja2 with [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/):

```
pip install jinja2
```